# Set Properties Inside Parameterless Constructor

Tags: c#, linq, parameters, constructor

I'm using linq to populate an object through a parameterless constructor.  I set a breakpoint on the constructor and noticed that none of the values for "this" had been populated.  One of the properties I'd like to have a is a sum total of some of the other properties.  Here is a stripped down example of what my class looks like:

```
// I'd like totalEstimatedUse to be the total of estimatedType1 + estimatedType2
public class EstimatedUse
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double estimatedType1 { get; set; }
    public double estimatedType2 { get; set; }
    public double totalEstimatedUse { get; set; } // I'd like this to be the sum
}

    // parameterless constructor - I cannot get anything to work inside this because
    // 'this' has no values when it's populated (from linq in my code)
    public EstimatedUse
    {
    }

    // here is a constructor that has parameters
    public EstimatedUse(string id, double estimatedType1, double estimatedType2)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.estimatedType1 = estimatedType1;
        this.estimatedType2 = estimatedType2;
        this.totalEstimatedUse = estimatedType1 + estimatedType2;
    }
```

The problem that happens is that I'm using linq to populate it and it goes to the paramterless constructor and that doesn't set my totalEstimatedUse.  What I'm doing to get around it is to set it a second time using my constructor with parameters.  Is there a more proper way to accomplish this rather than what I have below?

```
EstimatedUse estimatedUse = null;

// cutoff linq to keep example clean
.Select(e => new EstimatedUse
{
    ID = e.ProjectID,
    estimatedType1 = e.estimatedType1),
    estimatedType1 = e.estimatedType2),
}).FirstOrDefault();

// below is to set the length but I wish I could set in the parameterless constuctor if    
// it's possible    
estimatedUse = new EstimatedUse(estimatedUse.ID, estimatedUse.estimatedType1,
                                stimatedUse.estimatedType2);
```

Comment: Why not just call the (3 arg) constructor inside the `.Select` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you would be better served by changing your `totalEstimatedUse` property to a read-only property that automatically sums the values.

```
public class EstimatedUse
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double estimatedType1 { get; set; }
    public double estimatedType2 { get; set; }

    public double totalEstimatedUse
    {
        get { return this.estimatedType1 + this.estimatedType2; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way you don't have to set the value of the property upon creation, and it will stay up-to-date with your other values.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just change the `totalEstimatedUse` property's getter to automatically calculate the sum when you access it:

```
public class EstimatedUse
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double estimatedType1 { get; set; }
    public double estimatedType2 { get; set; }
    public double totalEstimatedUse { get { return estimatedType1 + estimatedType2; }
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed to do.  Having the values automatically calculated is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the values in the constructor, you're using the object initializer syntax.  That syntax creates the object by calling its constructor and *then* sets the properties specified.

To perform initialization of the object using the values you'll need to actually have a constructor that accepts them.

Of course the alternative is to avoid the need for initialization of the object in the first place.  In this particular case that would mean not holding the total sum in a field but rather computing the sum on request in the property getter.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to pass any parameter in constructor, then you should set the field you should have passed to constructor as global. and Set the value before making call to the class. Then inside constructor you can initialize it.

Though this is not the ideal way to do it, this is still an option. But you should see if you can pass a parameter to the constructor to set the values.

Answer (score 0):

Just eliminate the parameterless constructor, and use the one with parameters:

```
.Select(e => new EstimatedUse(e.ProjectID,e.estimatedType1e.estimatedType2))
.FirstOrDefault();
```

There is no reason to use an object initializer when you have a better constructor option.